# Ant Script after Tomcat Startup

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, startup

Is there anyway to write a hook to execute an ant script after the tomcat startup is completed. Tried to change the startup.bat to invoke ant script at the end, but the ant gets invoked before the tomcat has completely started.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376279/wait-until-tomcat-finishes-starting-up

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you provide few more inputs on the LifecycleListener implementation, so that I can invoke the necessary action from a Java class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way without dealing with anything related to Tomcat:

```
<!-- run tomcat here -->

<!-- wait for the server to be available -->
<waitfor>
    <http url="http://host:port">
</waitfor>

<!-- run other ant scripts from here... -->
```