# Tomcat to indicate in the logs when all webapps finished loading

Tags: tomcat

On my tomcat I have an application deployed which takes a long time to start up. Several web apps. Meanwhile I keep an eye in the logs, waiting for when the output starts so I know when everything was loaded.

Is there a way to output to the logs when all the modules finished loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the easy answer is that you can't.

I've found the Tomcat Lifecycleevents, but they are only for Tomcat events, and only for start and stop, not for finished starting.

Once Tomcat starts there's no way for it to know that a specific app has finished. Or even a group of apps.

[Wait until tomcat finishes starting up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376279/wait-until-tomcat-finishes-starting-up)

So there's no way to print to the logs. Bummer.

I'll make every web app provide a heartbeat and consider it "live" when all the heartbeats come back.